# sql bit allow null ef4

Tags: entity-framework-4, null, bit

I have in my database the following table

**table questions**

question_id int

answer  bit nullble

question string

```
 <Property Name="questionlog_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" oreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="question_id" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="answer" Type="bit" Nullable="true" />
```

in the entity framework, when i addObject it automatically set the answer to false (if no value has been given )

```
questions q = new questions(){
question="blalala"
} 
context.Addobject(q);
context.SaveChanges();
```

q.answer returns False

and error if i try to save it as null

```
questions q = new questions(){
question="blalala",
answer=null
} 
context.Addobject(q);
context.SaveChanges();
```

returns error

what can i do to set the default value as null

Comment: What is the exception/inner exception? and how does the questions entity look like?

Comment: i added the entity from the edmx

Comment: the error is cannot convert null to bool